# Spring Integration MessageDeliveryException

Tags: java, spring-integration

I am trying to test my Spring Integration setup, but am receiving

> "MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel".

I'm using a QueueChannel and I don't think it needs a handler (from what I can see in the docs).

I'm using [Spring Integration Java DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl) to define the integration flow programmatically, rather than using a context.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.QueueChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlows;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.channel.MessageChannels;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class SimplifiedIntegrationTest {
    @Test
    public void simpleTest() {
        MessageChannel inputChannel = MessageChannels.direct().get();
        QueueChannel outputChannel = MessageChannels.queue().get();
        IntegrationFlows.from(inputChannel).channel(outputChannel).get();

        inputChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("payload").build());

        Message<?> outMessage = outputChannel.receive(0);
        Assert.notNull(outMessage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IntegrationFlow` must always be registered in the context as a bean. I’m not sure what is the source making you think differently, but since you don’t register it as a bean in context, there is no that flow configuration magic done by the particular `BeanPostProcessor`. And that’s why you get that "Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel” error.

See `IntegrationFlowContext` if you register your Integration Flows manually: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/java-dsl.html#java-dsl-runtime-flows.

That doc is for Spring Integration 5.0, but `IntegrationFlowContext` behaves the same way in Java DSL 1.2.x.